# Installing profile on "Good" Mail application give someone admin permission on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, audit, appsec

My new enterprise use the app "GOOD" for the emails.
But to use it, I have to install a GOOD profile with description : "Install this profile to enroll to encrypted profile service". If I choose "Install", I'll get this warning (translated in english by me, sorry for the errors...) :

```
Installing this profile, will allow the administrator of "https://www.good.com/cerebus/mdm" to manage your iPhone remotly.
The administrator will be able to collect personal informations, add or remove accounts or restrictions, list your installed apps and manage them, and erase the data of your iPhone remotly
```

Because it's my private phone, I'm afraid to see this kind of warning... I should be the only one who has the right to erase my phone or manage things that aren't related to the Good App...

Can anyone tell me if there is a risk to have my datas collected or modified by another person and if it's really safe to install it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty standard message associated with MDM's and commonly seen with Bring Your Own Device (BYOD) plans.

The reason you're seeing this message and your company requires you to hook your phone up to the Mobile Device Management software is because they don't want unprotected company assets. This means if you leave the organization or go rogue, they want the ability to remove company property from your phone. Almost all modern MDM's allow for "select wipe" which will only remove content that has been pushed from your MDM profile, however it should be noted that an administrator of an MDM can remotely wipe your entire device should they see fit or make a mistake.

Safe is a relative term - the question you should be asking yourself is "Do you trust Good?" and "Do you trust the person who administers the server?" There is always an inherit risk with data collection anytime you connect any device to the internet, that risk doesn't just exist within MDM software.

Comment: Additionally, do you trust that Good placed sufficient security around their control protocols to avoid hijacking of the wipe controls.